# Solution for sharing code between apps in an iOS swift code base

Tags: android, ios, swift, xcode, gradle

In the Android code base, I can share code easily between apps by using Gradle and manage the dependencies between projects with Gradle. Is there an equivalent elegant solution for an iOS swift code base? Is there equivalent of Gradle "project" called "framework" in Swift/xCode world?

Comment: There are several ways to do this, but could you edit your question to perhaps provide a specific example of what you want to do so that it's easier for us to answer you?

Comment: Frameworks are supported in swift. You can create reusable components and have them in frameworks. Also take a look at [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) This is a 3rd party (open source) dependency manager for frameworks.